# Get last sent attachment discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I need to get the previously sent attachment in a channel to use as an argument

I used `await ctx.get_channel(channel).history(limit=10).flatten()[0]` to get previously sent messages I just don't know how I would go about getting the most recently sent **attachment** from the messages

Comment: Take a close look at the available attributes for `discord.Message` in the docs: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=message#discord.Message (hint: you don't have to look very far). Also - `history.flatten()` doesn't work anymore in 2.0, have a look at the Migration Guide: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/migrating.html#moving-away-from-custom-asynciterator if it still works for you, you should update because 1.7.x is deprecated as of now & will stop functioning somewhere this month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a code snippet I have from my bot that gets previously sent messages with their attachments. I think this is what you might need. It should print a link to the discord bucket with the attachment.

```
        messages = await channel.history(limit=10).flatten()
        for msg in messages: 
            try: 
                if msg.attachments: 
                    print((msg.attachments))
            except: print('no image')
```

Comment: As @stijndcl mentioned `history.flatten()` will be a deprecated function soon so this is only a temporary solution